# How to open URL in Virtual Reality (GearVR) App

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, gear-vr

I would like to know how to open URL on button click in Gear VR App. [Samsung Internet App](https://www.oculus.com/experiences/gear-vr/849609821813454/) in Oculus Store can be used in this scenario. Just like in 2D Non-VR Android Application, URL is automatically opened in Chrome or Firefox based on default browser. But in Gear VR app when I call

```
Application.OpenURL("http://www.google.co.uk");
```

the app freezes.

If this is not possible at all, then is there a way to show intractable Web-View in 3D space?

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had found the solution from [this post](https://forums.oculusvr.com/developer/discussion/39698/how-to-call-a-website-from-a-gear-vr-app) on Oculus forum.

Here is the working code:

```
public class OpenWebsiteOnHeadsetRemove : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Serialized
    public OVRManager m_OVRManager;
    #endregion

    #region Variables
    private bool m_UserPresent = true;
    private bool m_HasOpenedURL = false;
    #endregion

    #region Lifecycle
    private void Update () {
    #if UNITY_ANDROID
        bool isUserPresent = m_OVRManager.isUserPresent;

        if( m_UserPresent != isUserPresent )
        {
            if( isUserPresent == false && m_HasOpenedURL == false && Application.isEditor == false )
            {
                m_HasOpenedURL = true;
                Application.OpenURL("http://www.google.co.uk");
            }
        }

        m_UserPresent = isUserPresent;
    #endif
    }
    #endregion
}
```

> It will wait until the user has removed the headset before opening the
>   app to avoid the jarring visuals of the app freezing when you try to
>   open the URL. If the player takes the headset off and puts it back on
>   they will be returned to where they were in the game.

---

Hope this helps late users :)

Courtesy: [Glitchers Games](https://gist.github.com/glitchersgames)